# transfer function gets invalid opcode: INVALID InvalidInputRpcError: Missing or invalid parameters

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js, wagmi

I test it in React project.
It's working when I test the code in `Arbitrum Goerli` with USDT token.

Now I wnat to transfer USDT in `Ethereum Mainnet` by using wagmi pagckage, but when I trigger `usePrepareContractWrite` hook, I get the message error.

```
"Missing or invalid parameters.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

URL: https://cloudflare-eth.com
Request body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x7c...ce8f7","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000002ae4770c1461778013bd39a5437c2d20927801fb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000","to":"0xdA...31ec7"},"latest"]}
 
Raw Call Arguments:
  from:  0x7c...ce8f7
  to:    0xdA...831ec7
  data:  0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000002ae4770c1461778013bd39a5437c2d20927801fb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000
 
Contract Call:
  address:   0xdA...31ec7
  function:  transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
  args:              (0x2a...801Fb, 1000000000000000000)
  sender:    0x7c...ce8f7

Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/simulateContract.html
Details: invalid opcode: INVALID
Version: viem@1.19.7"
```

error screen shot:

[image]

Here is what I try:

version:

```
"wagmi": "^1.4.7",
"ethers": "^6.8.0",
```

code:

```
import {
    usePrepareContractWrite,
    useContractWrite,
} from 'wagmi';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

type Props = {
    usdtValue: string;
};

function useSendTokens(props?: Props) {
  // usdtValue is input value depends on user input number
  // ex: user types 5 means 5 USDT
    const units = Number(props?.usdtValue) * 1000000000000;

    const { config, error: prepareContractError } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        // Ethereum Mainnet USDT contract address
        address: '0xdA...31ec7',
        abi: [
            {
                constant: false,
                inputs: [
                    { name: '_to', type: 'address' },
                    { name: '_value', type: 'uint256' },
                ],
                name: 'transfer',
                outputs: [],
                payable: false,
                stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
                type: 'function',
            },
        ],
        functionName: 'transfer',
        args: [
            '0x2ae...801Fb', // proxyWallet address
            ethers.parseUnits(String(units), 6),
        ],
    });
  // print the error
  console.log('prepareContractError =>', prepareContractError);

    const { write, data, isSuccess, isLoading } = useContractWrite(config);

    return { write, data, isSuccess, isLoading, prepareContractError };
}

export default useSendTokens;
```

I have checked address is correct, because it's working on `Abritrum Goerli`.
I have no idea why I get the error.
Is any things I should change for `Ethereum Mainnet` ?